# In a Java recursive way, return the diff between 2 numbers digits

Tags: java, recursion

I got this quiestion and I can't figure out how to do it,

> Write a recursive function that gets 2 positive numbers and return the difference between these number digit

for example n1=24646468 and n2=248 it returns 5

```
        public static int diff(int n1, int n2){
        int sum1=0;
        int sum2=0;
        if(n1==0 && n2==0){
            return sum1-sum2;
        }
        if(n1>n2){
            if(n2==0){
                sum1++;
                return diff(n1/10, n2);
            }
            sum2++;
            return diff(n1,n2/10);
        }
        if(n1<n2){
            if(n1==0){
                sum2++;
                return diff(n1, n2/10);
            }
            sum1++;
            return diff(n1/10,n2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

it returns 0

if anyone knows whats wrong with my code thank you for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Start with two easier numbers, like `1` and `999`.

Answer (score 0):

The only `return` that is not a recursive call to `diff` returns `sum1-sum2` and those two variables are assigned to `0` or `return 0` at the last line.

You want to keep track of the state as you recurse.

Comment: How do I keep track of the state?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have used int and int operations that will lose floating point precision.

Use the same above code and convert the int to float before computing.
Try:

```
 public static int diff(int na, int nb, int sumn1, int sumn2){
        float n1 = na;
        float n2=nb;
        int sum1=sumn1;
        int sum2=sumn2;
        if(na==0 && nb==0){
            return sum1-sum2;
        }
        if(n1>n2){
            if(n2==0){
                sum1++;
                return diff((int)(n1/10f),(int) n2, sum1, sum2);
            }
            sum2++;
            return diff((int)n1,(int)(n2/10f), sum1,sum2);
        }
        if(n1<n2){
            if(n1==0){
                sum2++;
                return diff((int)n1, (int)(n2/10f), sum1, sum2);
            }
            sum1++;
            return diff((int)(n1/10f),(int)n2, sum1,sum2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Updated the spoon :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for whoever commented I think I found the solution:

```
        public static int diff(int n1, int n2, int sum1, int sum2){
        if((n1==0 && n2==0)&& sum1>sum2){
            return sum1-sum2;
        }
        if((n1==0 && n2==0)&& sum1<sum2){
            return sum2-sum1;
        }
        if(n1>n2){
            if(n2==0){
                sum1++;
                return diff(n1/10, n2, sum1, sum2);
            }
            sum2++;
            return diff(n1,n2/10, sum1, sum2);
        }
        if(n1<n2){
            if(n1==0){
                sum2++;
                return diff(n1, n2/10, sum1, sum2);
            }
            sum1++;
            return diff(n1/10,n2, sum1, sum2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I just need to hope they will allow me to add that the function recieves sum1 and sum2 aswell